# Visio Data Visualizer

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to use the Visio Data Visualizer for the first time. I have followed the directions on the process map provided by Microsoft. However, when I select the table in the process map sheet, the only export options I see are Export Table to Sharepoint List or Export Table to Visio PivotDiagram. I want a regular Visio diagram, not a pivot diagram. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

What are the version of Excel and Visio you are using? As far as I know, the ability to use the Data Visualizer templates is only available with Visio Online Plan 2. If you're not sure what version of Visio you're using, select File > Account > About Visio. For more information, read [Data Visualizer frequently asked questions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/data-visualizer-frequently-asked-questions-e1273f3a-eafb-4e70-ada1-900fca4629c0).

Based on my tests and research, I can use Visio Online Plan 2 and Excel for Office 365 to [create a Data Visualizer diagram](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-data-visualizer-diagram-17211b46-d144-4ca2-9ea7-b0f48f0ae0a6#faststart). I can see the option "Export Table to Visio Diagram" in my Excel for Office 365 installed together with Visio Online Plan 2. If you don't have Visio Online Plan 2 installed, you won't get the option in Excel and you can't use the feature"create a Data Visualizer diagram".

[image]

Here are some screenshots in Excel 2013 and Excel for Office 365 without Visio Online Plan 2 installed.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi Herb;  I do have online plan 2 but based on your answer it does not seem to have been set up correctly. I have contacted my IS group to help. Thank you!

Comment: You can create a new drawing based on the template called ''Basic Flowchart - Data   Visualizer" in Visio Online Plan 2 directly. Follow the wizard step by step. For more detailed steps, read [Create a Data Visualizer diagram](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-data-visualizer-diagram-17211b46-d144-4ca2-9ea7-b0f48f0ae0a6). In addition, I also suggest [you online repair your Office 365 and Visio from Control Panel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b) to have a check.

Comment: Hi Herb; I don't have admin rights for my work computer but thanks to your help I was able to insist that IS install Visio and the on-line plan correctly. It all works now! Thanks so much.